# Div's not filling container

Tags: css

I have a problem with css.
Let's  assume the following structure

```
<div id='maincontainer'>
  <div id='item'>
     <div id='itemimage'> </div>
     <div id='itemtext'> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now. For every item in the database it prints an item, with the corresponding image and text. Lets say i have 4 items in my database. It prints the first one fine, and the second, but the third and fourth get printed out of the container.

My maincontainer has a minimum height, which extends with the height of the itemdiv. But after two items, it stops extending.

Do you have any idea's.

```
#maincontainer {

    font-size:11px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    margin-top:60px;   
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    min-height:50px;
    height:auto!important;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:650px;
    position:relative; 
    color:#465258;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid black;



}

#item  
{

    height:170px;
    width:650px;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
}

#itemimage
{

    float:left;
    height:135px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;

}

#item_text
{

     color:#465258;
     width:435px;     
     margin-top:-135px;
     height:110px;   
     float:right;
     position:relative;
     padding-top:10px;
     padding-bottom:10px;
     clear:both;
}
```

Comment: can you post the css you have?

Comment: Oke, i fixed it. I changed my whole css and removed a mistake in the html which did not end the </div>

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a height On the div? It should just stretch vertically to fit its contents. Unless you are using floats on the items and not containing them with float clearing methods.

Comment: I am using floats, as you can see in the css i just posted

Comment: Tried it, did not work. I believe the problem does not lay with the floats, since it prints the first two items perfectly

Comment: Can you set up a sample page in jsbin.com or jsfiddle.com

Comment: The problem with that is that it is part of a much larger system, and i grab the info for the items out of a database.